# How to put a background image on a site

Tags: html, css

I have this site: http://www.problemio.com which currently has a solid-colored background and the body has a width of about 1000px.

My designer gave me a background image like this: http://problemio.com/img/ui/background_image.png

I am not sure if background images are supposed to be white in the middle like that.  And I am not sure how to make this image fit around my wider frame of the body of the actual website.

Any idea if it is possible to make this my background image?

Here are my currently css styles for the outer shell:

```
body, html 
{
    #padding: 5px;
}

body 
{
    font-family:  "Century Gothic",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: #5C5957;
}

 /* makes the background of the top bar gray */
.container 
{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;

    overflow:hidden;
    width:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and here are the more complete styles:

http://problemio.com/main.css

Thanks!!

Comment: Your designer should provide the complete background without that white box.

Comment: And when he does, add to your body element: background: url(http://problemio.com/img/ui/background_image.png) transparent top left fixed no-repeat;

Comment: @Grillz so should all the background images always be complete images and not ones with a kind of a hole in the middle like in this case?

Comment: @Grillz also, what is the best way to make the image appear that it extends all the way down the page even if the image isn't infinitely tall?  Thanks!!

Comment: That "fixed" part will make the image stay put (not scroll down the page), so as long as it covers the browser window it should be fine.

Comment: It's not wrong exactly to have that white spot, but he is certainly limiting you to a strange design. What he sent is more of a representation of what he wants it to look like rather than the *resource* you need to use for the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body 
{
    font-family:  "Century Gothic",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    background:url(smiley.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Here `background-size` only support for CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

Something of this kind:

```
background-image:url('url/of/your/image');
```

Comment: yeah I get that, but in this case, the image won't wrap perfectly around because it is smaller in proportions than the layout.  I am not sure it is possible to accomplish with just that line of code.